# Object array to char array

Tags: java

I am passing a char array ab[][] from serlet1 to ABC.jsp by:
`request.setAttribute("grid", ab);`

After I retrieve it in `ABC.jsp`:
`Object [][] array = request.getAttribute("grid");`
How do I convert it to char array?

I can't find examples of objectToChar or other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it:

`char[][] myCharArray = (char[][])request.getAttribute("grid");`

Attributes are stored in map that can store values of any type. What you put is what you get. If you put char array you get char array.

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit cast

char[][] array = (char[][])(request.getAttribute("grid"));